# Identification of vintage sloping window piece

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to identify the yellow one, the red 60598 ones are for reference.

[image] [image]

This is definitely Lego, it is written in the hollow studs. It does not have a part number underneath, only an 01 and a separate 3. I can’t find it in any of the usual databases.

The yellow I’m trying to identify is 1x4 at the base, 3 bricks tall, leans back by on row at the top but is slightly wider than 4 studs at the top approx 4.5 so the overall dimensions are 2 x 4.5 x 3.

Comment: Looks like a LEGO Fabuland windscreen...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the hint from Uli I was able to find it:

[image]

[image]

(All credit to Uli for the find :)

Answer (score 13):

Must be

- Fabuland Front Window Squared Small, Part **x652** on peeron.com

[image]

*(image source peeron.com)*

Comment: We must have posted at nearly the same time.  You didn't post an answer after about 10 minutes so I ran with your hunch. Nice find, I had no idea this existed.

Comment: @JohnnyB photo finish in fact : ) couldn't find it on bricklink in time, that's why I checked peeron, too. took me some minutes...

Comment: It's called "Fabuland Window Squared Small", with part number fabai1 on bricklink.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like part 4447 window 4x4x3 Roof.[image]

Comment: It does look like it, but part# 4447 has squared corners and indents/holes for glass. The part in the picture has rounded inner edges and no indents/holes.

Comment: And this is not that bit wider at the top.